# Resharper 7 - vbhtml support?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, resharper, resharper-7.1

Is it possible to allow `vbhtml` support using `Resharper 7` (latest stable version 7.1.3000.2254) in Razor files?

My new customer uses VB.NET accross all their applications, and i cannot seem to get Resharper's Razor syntax refactoring and tools support in `.vbhtml` files.

It works fine if I rename the views to `.cshtml` (but then I have to change all the keywords and it's a terrible idea to start mixing vbhtml and cshtml files).

- **Anyone knows if it's my current install that's wrong or if this is a *normal* behavior?**
- **Alternately, can anyone test if Resharper's refactoring tools work in `.vbhtml` files (ie., Code clean-up `[ctrl+e, c]`, Surround With `[ctrl+e, u]`, Move to resource `[ctrl+r, o]`, etc.) ?**

Note: i also tested using the Resharper 8 EAP and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ReSharper doesn't support vbhtml.

Comment: Looks like you're right! Well, hopefully they have plans to add such a feature in the next versions.

Comment: I am afraid to disappoint you, but there are no plans for near future.